# What are some resources for learning about x-ray powder diffraction?

Tags: resource-recommendations, x-ray-crystallography

I am looking for up-to-date, applied resources to learn about x-ray powder diffraction. There is a lot of jargon with which I am unfamiliar.  I am trying to refine theoretical curves to collected data using the program Maud using the Rietveld Method but I am unsure about which parameters to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

As with any new thing one the best ways to do it is to look for publications. If you don't understand the jargon/notation, go to their references and look at those papers and keep recursively applying that method until you go back far enough to where you understand, then you can read back up to the first one.

**Edit**: I understand this is not a resource recommendation *per se*, but it is a general rule of thumb for researching when you find yourself immersed in notation/jargon/terminology with which you are not familiar.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer myself to start from an introductory book or a lecture before diving into research papers.

The most often recommended book on the rietveld_l mailing list (which is the biggest mailing list about powder diffraction) is:

[Fundamentals of Powder Diffraction and Structural Characterization of Materials](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387095783) by Vitalij K. Pecharsky & Peter Y. Zavalij.

Note that rietveld_l is a low-traffic list and most-often recommended there means a few times per decade.